# LDAP - unable to add entries

Tags: ldap

Im using LDAP Admin Tool Professional 6.0
When i try to add an entry or try to add an attribute to an existing record,I get this error:

```
Strong Authentication Required
LDAPException: Strong Authentication Required (8) Strong Authentication Required
LDAPException: Server Message: modifications require authentication
LDAPException: Matched DN:
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

"modifications require authentication" indicates that you did not authenticate to the LDAP server at all, but doing an anonymous bind. While you may read a lot of things as anonymous user, depending on the ACL of the server, all server implementations I know do not allow write operations without authentication.

So you need to specify "Bind DN" and "Bind Password" in your LDAP client software to make any modifications to the data stored in the LDAP directory.

Answer (score 1):

The message is very clear. The administrators require a stronger authentication scheme. Use something stronger with the correct credentials and the authentication will succeed - assuming you are trying to authenticate before the add. If you are trying to add entries without authenticating at all, note that directory server administrators may forbid it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your "Admin Tool Professional 6.0" but LDAP is not accepting your login.
Check your DN